# Generics inside if not taking the proper type

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to achieve a function that serialize everything that is a Map class to an object. What I meant with that is: I'm trying to create a function that if receives an object will check every attribute and if some of them is a Map it will return an object there. Also in case that the function receives an Array of Map will return an Array of objects.

I have created this types:

```
type InputMapToObject =
    | Map<keyof any, unknown>
    | Record<keyof any, unknown>
    | unknown[];

type ReturnMapToObject<T extends InputMapToObject> = T extends Map<
    infer KMap extends keyof any,
    infer VMap
>
    ? Record<
          KMap,
          VMap extends InputMapToObject ? ReturnMapToObject<VMap> : VMap
      >
    : T extends object
    ? {
          [P in keyof T]: T[P] extends InputMapToObject
              ? ReturnMapToObject<T[P]>
              : T[P];
      }
    : T extends (infer VArray)[]
    ? VArray extends InputMapToObject
        ? ReturnMapToObject<VArray>[]
        : VArray[]
    : never;
```

This type works perfect, here a test where you can see that the type is working:

```
interface TestingType {
    testMap: Map<string, number>;
    testArray: Array<number>;
    testArray2: Array<Map<string, string>>;
}

const test: ReturnMapToObject<TestingType> = {
    testMap: {
        string: 0,
    },
    testArray: [0],
    testArray2: [{ string: 'string' }],
};
```

The problem that I have is on the function `mapToObject` (the other functions are just helpers):

```
export function mapToObject<T extends InputMapToObject>(
    itemToConvert: T
): ReturnMapToObject<T> {
    if (itemToConvert instanceof Map) {
        return [...itemToConvert.entries()].reduce((acc, [key, value]) => {
            acc[key] = value;
            return acc;
        }, {} as ReturnMapToObject<T>);
    }

    if (Array.isArray(itemToConvert)) {
        return itemToConvert.map((item) => {
            if (isRecursiveValue(item)) {
                return mapToObject(item);
            }
            return item;
        });
    }

    return getObjectEntries(itemToConvert).reduce((acc, [key, value]) => {
        if (isRecursiveValue(value)) {
            acc[key] = mapToObject(value);
        } else {
            acc[key] = value;
        }

        return acc;
    }, {} as ReturnMapToObject<T>);
}

function isRecursiveValue(item: any): item is InputMapToObject {
    if (item instanceof Map) return true;
    if (Array.isArray(item)) return true;
    if (item && typeof item === 'object') return true;
    return false;
}

function getObjectEntries<T extends Record<any, any>>(
    value: T
): [keyof any, T[keyof T]][] {
    return Object.entries(value) as [keyof any, T[keyof T]][];
}
```

I think the function `mapToObject` would work as expected with JavaScript, but I'm having type errors. For example I do have an error on the first reducer.If the input is a Map then I use the reduce method to convert the entries to a object. The problem there is that I try to type the initial object, so I do as `ReturnMapToObject<T>` but TypeScript is interpreting as that T could be anything but not, it can only be a Map.

This is the error that I'm getting doing `acc[key] = value`:

```
Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string | number | symbol' can't be used to index type 'object | unknown[] | Record<string | number | symbol, unknown>'.
  No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type 'object | unknown[] | Record<string | number | symbol, unknown>'.ts(7053)
(parameter) acc: object | unknown[] | Record<string | number | symbol, unknown>
```

If TypeScript would recognize properly that T inside the Map instance if acc would be: `Record<string | number | symbol, unknown>` because as it's defined on the `ReturnMapToObject` if T extends Map then it will return a Record.

Comment: ① When I paste that into my own IDE I get several errors you're not asking about, and the issue you are apparently asking about doesn't jump out at me.  You say "the function" but the code has several functions, and when you say "not working properly" it's not obvious to me what you mean. Could you [edit] to address these? ② There is almost no chance you can implement a generic function that returns a conditional type without using a bunch of type assertions (see [ms/TS#33912](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/33912)), so if it "should work properly" then just assert and move on.

Comment: Yes, sorry I haven't explained well the problem. I updated the question, so I think now it's clear about the problem. I'm using assertions but probably I need more of them? not sure how to continue. Thank you for your help

Comment: TypeScript can't narrow or re-constrain generic type parameters via control flow analysis.  If you have a value `t` of generic type `T`, and you check (say) `t instanceof Map`, you can narrow `t` from `T` to `T & Map`, but the type `T` itself is not changed, for good reasons. Right now TS doesn't have support for the kind of logic you're doing; if you're sure your function is correct then just [assert things to suppress the errors](https://tsplay.dev/NaRbBm) and move on.  Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: Yes, that answers my question! hope in the future I can improve this code then! thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TypeScript can't [narrow](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html) or re-[constrain](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) [generic type parameters](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) via [control flow analysis](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#control-flow-analysis).  So when you check, for example, `itemToConvert instanceof Map`, the apparent type of `itemToConvert` can be narrowed from `T` to (something like) `T & Map`, but the type parameter `T` *itself* stays the same.

This is for a good reason: you can think of a type as something like the set of all possible acceptable values.  Let's take the type `string`.  If I say that the value  `s` is of generic type `S extends string`, and I check that `s === "abc"`, now I  know that the *value* `s` is `"abc"`, but I really don't know anything more about the *type* `S`.  Maybe `S` is the string literal type `"abc"`, or maybe it's a [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) of such types like `"abc" | "def" | "ghi"`, or maybe it's `string`.  All of those would be consistent with `s === "abc"`.  It's like if I pull a marble (value) out of a bag (type) and then check the color of the marble, that tells me a lot about the marble, and *very little* about the bag and the colors of marbles it contains.

So you can't just "narrow" a generic type parameter the way you narrow the apparent type of a value, at least not without adding new features to the language.  One such feature is requested at [microsoft/TypeScript#27808](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/27808), in which you'd be able to say something like `T oneof InputMapToObject` meaning that `T` is known to be exactly one of the (presumed mutually exclusive) union members of `InputMapToObject`.  Then when you check whether `itemToConvert instanceof Map`, you can say that `T` itself is either `Map<keyof any, unknown>` or `oneof Record<keyof any, unknown> | unknown[]`, and the rest of the code might compile as intended.  But for now it's not part of the language.

This limitation is really obvious and painful when you try to implement a generic function that returns a [conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html) depending on the generic type parameters, like you're doing with `ReturnMapToObject<T>`.  There's another  open feature request for generic conditional function implementations at [microsoft/TypeScript#33912](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/33912), and again, it's not yet part of the langauge.

---

Until and unless something changes here, you'll have to work around it.  Assuming you don't want to completely refactor things, the most expedient workaround is to use something like [type assertions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) to just tell the compiler not to complain.  This is reasonable if you're sure that the implementation is correct but the compiler isn't... and it also means you need to be careful, since the compiler can't catch your mistakes if you do this.

Here's one way to do the assertions:

```
export function mapToObject<T extends InputMapToObject>(
    itemToConvert: T
): ReturnMapToObject<T> {
    if (itemToConvert instanceof Map) {
        return [...itemToConvert.entries()].reduce((acc, [key, value]) => {
            acc[key] = value;
            return acc;
        }, {} as any); // <-- just use any
    }

    if (Array.isArray(itemToConvert)) {
        return itemToConvert.map((item) => {
            if (isRecursiveValue(item)) {
                return mapToObject(item);
            }
            return item;
        }) as ReturnMapToObject<T>; // <-- just assert
    }

    return getObjectEntries(itemToConvert).reduce((acc, [key, value]) => {
        if (isRecursiveValue(value)) {
            acc[key] = mapToObject(value);
        } else {
            acc[key] = value;
        }

        return acc;
    }, {} as any); // just use any
}
```

You could try more accurate types other than [the `any` type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#any), which might catch some egregious errors.  And/or you could make your function a single-call-signature [overload](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#function-overloads) which also allows a looser implementation than the call signature(s):

```
function mapToObject<T extends InputMapToObject>(
    itemToConvert: T
): ReturnMapToObject<T>;

function mapToObject<T extends InputMapToObject>(itemToConvert: T):
    ReturnMapToObject<InputMapToObject> {

    if (itemToConvert instanceof Map) {
        return [...itemToConvert.entries()].
            reduce<Record<keyof any, unknown>>((acc, [key, value]) => {
                acc[key] = value;
                return acc;
            }, {});
    }

    if (Array.isArray(itemToConvert)) {
        return itemToConvert.map((item) => {
            if (isRecursiveValue(item)) {
                return mapToObject(item);
            }
            return item;
        })
    }

    return getObjectEntries(itemToConvert).
        reduce<Record<keyof any, unknown>>((acc, [key, value]) => {
            if (isRecursiveValue(value)) {
                acc[key] = mapToObject(value);
            } else {
                acc[key] = value;
            }
            return acc;
        }, {});
}
```

There are any of a number of such workarounds, but if you want to keep your current implementation, all of them will require that you loosen some of the type checking to avoid these (presumably) false warnings.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=6&noErrorTruncation=true&ts=5.1.3#code/C4TwDgpgBAkgdmArsAsgQzAFQPYHkBGAVhAMbBQC8AsAFBT1QA+U6YAPANYQjYBmUaOCAA0URHA5xsAdzgA+WgyZQASqWwAnACadufAUNHjJM+YobNjU2QG0AugG5atUJFURgiDXFY4CxMjZMKAgAD2AIOC0AZ1gEZF88IlJgOUooYLCIqNjWNnN6AEs4XggNKABpVhDwyJioLh5+QRECqGLS8oA1VloFOgYAfncSTR02pSqMYQmGHowa7Pr4JFQMP2SyKGG1T29E-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-A0hE-HYEJcAieQxTWoI5r6KwrIAfKSj7nsAI2AAdLZvEaVpOnWZEwFWlSrJ2NZ+5aIg5pUlSZokKINiNKImpoDOiAQHYJkUIpgFKIFIXcBCHbhZFECJvi5nSQCgVZciUGdiSAixC0rIOD2faDsOhCIFW9XQC0pL6spqmRtZq6RmpfGCcJZTAKyJlKdlFnou06l9dpA3WYxYD+fZsXxWZ2UqVANLRGoJBeNEhTal0EVRT1-pDaZ2XnVAY3eFAc0bAix0VQlDBlhdDBXQC9kFUoJImce7iWRxRyYCGVX9kOUB1VWx7RANLUGjlllQLaHhyQAonArnRMdU06ayXkQD5fkBSQQVQMlIhQOlUUxZQy3nWtG1bTte0QAdGVUlTECnSNr1JY0qU3UxKQc4dXNfc9IQzjDZ2vQIJPkwLnPi-QZaAe9cskAVRXvCVf3lZVvYQ-VX7S81NCqzQ1FwLR9GC7JLwpixWRQnEqyA2QXE8ZNmn9aJ4k0JJ-1ikL2IlgaVs2wxIfAI79xLGxbvR1x9k4wNdySW0dYYvbzEwgKd0pMtPGqSnPvTaJ-z6dbEBGRgw1q7lZO2Z13uOTNLnem5HnWU99Deb5EBsFtYy6E0BgU1YpjFv5gXBaFlOizTcUy7LDB8yl6RK73yLq-l2-az9WutQwDMdV1GbY2XuP1ytfeN6XbeibNGALepS0rxdDOrkzGi7ftosPRvqvBG41bpCjIA9ZWhVt7q0+oBH6cM2jq2RsANGGNO5Ywfr7QaPdb6XQJgPIe6htCj30C0IwEhrDyC4sTUm5MwqL3fjzT+JdNqkGZv-dmnNubb0SvLfm6QwFyRFhlR6eDvqS2lsw1e68QCK1FlA76MDG57zwQfMRFtaARxtLbb+7Df4szZkdeyFxyoXHsu0BOsIc4pA-l-dSldgAGRrvwYy+DEY5iigVU+GZOrRG6otEy6tPGZWLutCxAAyCJ1ZHT6AsRQBJUAdzPARDuIJjcQkFXVqaKWoTzb6m0XRAEKC0GYydg8eow8SHkPHtPNonN-aB3JmQwwGRmnAjsHYewH91ZyWcugwobluGlTJo0FpFMcRjI6V04k5sgA)